# What's the development package for Qt5 in 14.04

Tags: package-management, qt, qt5

I want to build a Qt5 example on my desktop machine. I installed `qt5-default` and `qtdeclarative5-dev`, but I'm still getting this error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick qml
```

Which package should be installed for compiling? In the Qt4 times it was simply `libqt4-dev`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to install

```
qtdeclarative5-dev
```

Comment: It's already installed, version `5.2.1-8build1`

Comment: what about `qtdeclarative5-dev`?

Comment: It's definitely `qtdeclarative5-dev`. Can you edit the answer body and add it, please?

Answer (score 91):

[List of all Qt5 developement packages, available on Ubuntu](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ycob0pe97H0Bz70WWXgx1-wNp6cVr1OcdQFaf5N7s8/edit?usp=sharing).

```
Qt module           dev package                         lib package
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
bluetooth           qtconnectivity5-dev                 libqt5bluetooth5
concurrent          qtbase5-dev                         libqt5concurrent5
connectivity        qtmobility-dev                      libqtconnectivity1
contacts            qtmobility-dev                      libqt5contacts5
core                qtbase5-dev                         libqt5core5a
dbus                qtbase5-dev                         libqt5dbus5
designer            qttools5-dev                        libqt5designer5
designercomponents  qttools5-dev                        libqt5designercomponents5
feedback            qtmobility-dev                      libqt5feedback5
gallery             qtmobility-dev                      libqtgallery1
gui                 qtbase5-dev                         libqt5gui5
help                qttools5-dev                        libqt5help5
location            qtmobility-dev                      libqt5location5
multimedia          qtmultimedia5-dev                   libqt5multimedia5
multimediakit       qtmobility-dev                      libqtmultimediakit1
network             qtbase5-dev                         libqt5network5
networkauth         libqt5networkauth5-dev              libqt5networkauth5
nfc                 qtconnectivity5-dev                 libqt5nfc5
opengl              libqt5opengl5-dev                   libqt5opengl5
organizer           qtmobility-dev                      libqt5organizer5
positioning         qtpositioning5-dev                  libqt5positioning5
printsupport        qtbase5-dev                         libqt5printsupport5
publishsubscribe    qtmobility-dev                      libqt5publishsubscribe5
qml                 qtdeclarative5-dev                  libqt5qml5
quick               qtdeclarative5-dev                  libqt5quick5
quickparticles      qtdeclarative5-dev                  libqt5quickparticles5
quicktest           qtdeclarative5-dev                  libqt5quicktest5
quickwidgets        qtdeclarative5-dev                  libqt5quickwidgets5
script              qtscript5-dev                       libqt5script5
scripttools         qtscript5-dev                       libqt5scripttools5
sensors             qtmobility-dev, libqt5sensors5-dev  libqt5sensors5
serialport          libqt5serialport5-dev               libqt5serialport5
serviceframework    qtmobility-dev                      libqt5serviceframework5
sql                 qtbase5-dev                         libqt5sql5
svg                 libqt5svg5-dev                      libqt5svg5
systeminfo          qtmobility-dev                      libqt5systeminfo5
test                qtbase5-dev                         libqt5test5
uitools             qttools5-dev                        ?
versit              qtmobility-dev                      libqtversit1
webchannel          ?                                   ?
webkit              libqt5webkit5-dev                   libqt5webkit5
websockets          libqt5websockets5-dev               libqt5websockets5
widgets             qtbase5-dev                         libqt5widgets5
x11extras           libqt5x11extras5-dev                libqt5x11extras5
xml                 qtbase5-dev                         libqt5xml5
xmlpatterns         libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev              libqt5xmlpatterns5
```

Comment: This is really helpful to figure out what to install when a cmake build gives something like `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5::Help`.  That kind of failure mode seems to be typical for cmake.

Comment: This is very useful!

Comment: Is there a simple way to install all of these *-dev packages at once?

Comment: You can try something like ``apt-get install qt5*-dev``

Comment: A piece of advice. Try and avoid the use of * with any aptitude commands! My friend had to restart his computer because `apt remove wine*` deleted all packages containing the substring `win` in it. Be extremely careful with this.

Answer (score 44):

The answer to the title is:

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
```

For your specific problem, the answers above are correct, though.

Answer (score 6):

You can obtain the list of all Qt development packages to choose from with this command:

```
apt list "libqt5*-dev" "qt*-dev"
```

It will show the packages available in your current Ubuntu repositories based on the package names for development packages that can be observed in the [answer by @gossen](https://askubuntu.com/a/577334). For details about the command and similar commands, [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411474).

Comment: I would say this is slightly better: `apt list "libqt5*-dev" "qt*5-dev"`

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls
```

Validate the installation, through::

```
qtchooser -print-env
```

Output might resemble as follows (based on package available for your Ubuntu version):

```
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

Reference [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/36094/solved-qt5-for-debian-linux/8).