# How are Qt modules/classes distributed amongst Ubuntu packages?

Tags: package-management, qt, packaging, qt5

For example, I know that I need the `core` dependency or the `network` one. In other words I have the following lines in qbs project file

```
Depends { name: "Qt.core" }
Depends { name: "Qt.network" }
```

Now, my question is how can I figure out which packages I need to install?

PS This question was partially answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508503/whats-the-development-package-for-qt5-in-14-04), but (1) there is no generic explanation and, what is more important, (2) the table looks outdated (there is no `mqtt` module, for example, in the table). So I would like to understand the underlying logic.