# Error with Qtcreator when running project "error: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quickwidgets svg quick"

Tags: qt, qml, svg

I have successfully installed Qtcreator 5.9.7 on Linux 18.04, checked by running example project. Now I am trying to run my old project, created on 5.7.1 on Desktop PC and getting the following error.

```
error: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quickwidgets svg quick
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: What worked for me was **sudo apt install qt5-default**

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution, install `qtdeclarative5-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

[What's the development package for Qt5 in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508503/whats-the-development-package-for-qt5-in-14-04)