# scap-workbench package for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04

Were can I find scap-workbench package for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS? It seems available for 18.04 but I can't find it for 20.04.

Comment: It can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/OpenSCAP/scap-workbench/releases) and build it. The directions are in the 'readme' and don't look terribly difficult to follow, though I didn't bother trying it personally. It's just cut/paste some commands into the terminal.

Comment: Well according to the README, the dependencies required are for RHEL. What are the equivalents of openscap-devel qt5-devel openssh-askpass packages for ubuntu?

Comment: I *think* `libopenscap-dev` `not sure` and `lxqt-openssh-askpass` *maybe*. In my quick scan, I did not notice that. You may need to ask the authors. In fact, asking them would be your best bet. You can also try downloading a .deb for 18.04 and seeing if you can meet the dependencies. There are probably better sources, but check here: https://pkgs.org/download/scap-workbench

Comment: libopenscap-dev and lxqt-openssh-askpass seems correct. I installed them. How about qt5-devel?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Use `apt-cache search qt5-dev` and see if anything jumps out at you, as you'd be more likely to spot it than I would. It's probably one of those - but I'm not sure which.

Comment: I think I got it by referencing https://askubuntu.com/questions/508503/whats-the-development-package-for-qt5-in-14-04. Its building now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a SuSE guy and this is my first ubuntu experience so thanks again.

Comment: Excellent. If you get a minute, it might be worth documenting it by answering your own question. That way, the next person can follow your path more easily.

Comment: As far as  the qt5-devel requirement, I had to install libqt5xmlpatterns5 and libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev. That seemed to bring in a lot of dependencies. I suspect what I got was qtbase5-dev.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on 20.04.1

Note: markh, the user that asked this question, had already solved this as shown in the comments. I've just formalised it into an answer for future visitors.

I downloaded a tarball from releases on the Github page: https://github.com/OpenSCAP/scap-workbench/releases but you could also choose to clone the Git repo.

I installed these packages, some were already present on my system but that's fine.

```
apt install build-essential cmake libopenscap-dev lxqt-openssh-askpass qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev
```

asciidoc is not required if you download the tarball but you should install it if you used the Git repo so that you have documentation generated

```
apt install asciidoc
```

Then follow the readme:

```
mkdir build ; cd build 
cmake ../
make
```

For me, make finished with

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable scap-workbench
[100%] Built target scap-workbench
```

I can now run the workbench from the build directory with

```
./scap-workbench
```

Comment: Note, I also specifically (now) needed `apt install -y pkg-config`.  Also, there is an make `install` rule as well which copies files to appropriate locations (for layman, execute `make install` after the `make` invocation completes).

Answer (score 2):

You can build the Debian scap-workbench 1.2.1 package on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
apt install build-essential cmake libopenscap-dev qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev asciidoc debhelper devscripts quilt
```

```
mkdir build-scap-workbench
cd build-scap-workbench
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/scap-workbench/scap-workbench_1.2.1-1.dsc
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/scap-workbench/scap-workbench_1.2.1-1.debian.tar.xz
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/scap-workbench/scap-workbench_1.2.1.orig.tar.bz2
dpkg-source -x scap-workbench_1.2.1-1.dsc
cd scap-workbench-1.2.1/
sensible-editor debian/control
At line 16 change this:
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 13),
into this:
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 12),
quilt pop debian/patches/0002-Fix-build-warning.patch 
sensible-editor src/TailoringWindow.cpp
At line 648 change this:
    mCollapsedItemIds = QSet<QString>(list.begin(), list.end());
into this:
    mCollapsedItemIds = QSet<QString>::fromList(list);
quilt refresh
dch -i
Add a description and change UNRELEASED to focal
debuild -uc -us -I -i
cd ..
dpkg -i scap-workbench_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb
```